# Javascript to be applied on different react pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to apply javascript code the most of the react page. Basically exporting from a helper file and importing on all those pages where it's needed. The following code works pretty well on a single page,

```
tableRadius() {
    var tableHeader = document.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0].offsetHeight;
    var topValue = this.offsetTop - this.scrollTop;
    var top = Math.round(topValue + tableHeader);

    var verticalScroll = document.querySelector(".radius-wrapper");
    verticalScroll.setAttribute("style", "top:" + top + "px");
    return;
}

componentDidMount() {
    const table = document.getElementById("dispatchTable");
    table.addEventListener("scroll", this.tableRadius);
}
```

After, I tried adding this code to the helper file so that i can use it accross the different pages. I don't know if i did it right but, i tried adding the **tablueRadius** function in a helper file but it had issues. 
Here it is how i did,

page.js

```
import { tableRadius } from '../../../services';

class Dispatcher extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tableRadius = tableRadius();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const table = document.getElementById("dispatchTable");
    table.addEventListener("scroll", this.tableRadius);
  }

}
```

Helper file, Services

```
export function tableRadius() {
  var tableHeader = document.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0].offsetHeight;
  var topValue = this.offsetTop - this.scrollTop;
  var top = Math.round(topValue + tableHeader);

  var verticalScroll = document.querySelector(".radius-wrapper");
  verticalScroll.setAttribute("style", "top:" + top + "px");

  return;  
}
```

Here, i get an error on helper file that says, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined`

Am i doing it right? Or there is a bettery way? can you please suggest ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `tableRadius` in constructor. You need to just assign it.

```
class Dispatcher extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tableRadius = tableRadius;
  }
```

Also, along with `React`, prefer not to use `DOM` api to directly manipulate elements. Instead take advantage of `React` ecosystem. Write your elements inside `JSX` and add required listeners over there.

Comment: Thanks bro, I am very new to React, Don't have any idea about it. Your Solution solved my problem though. Btw, can you tell me where I can learn the best about the react ecosystem? I don't think it is going to be easy?

Comment: I would recommend the official docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html